# Observable class and ToObservable missing from System.Reactive 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

After installing the 3.0 version of System.Reactive.Core from Nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Core), I can't get the Observable class to compile or appear. The `ToObservable` extention method is also missing from my generic `List<>`.

I have the following packages installed and referenced in my project (.NET v4.6.1 C# console project):

`System.Reactive.Core (3.0.0.0)
System.Reactive.Interfaces (3.0.0.0)
System.Reactive.Windows.Threading (3.0.0.0)`

I am using the following:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.PlatformServices;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;`
```

And still I'm getting errormessages "The name 'Observable' does not exist in the current context" and "List does not contain a definition for 'ToObservable'...".

I want to get a "HelloWorld" example up and running and I was hoping to use `Observable.Range`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to [`Install-Package System.Reactive`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/)

> Reactive Extensions Main Library combining the interfaces, core, LINQ, and platform services libraries.

With the package, you will get the static `Observable` class and also the extensions for `IEnumerable`.

If you don't want to install platform services, you can also run these to get the features you need.

```
Install-Package System.Reactive.Core
Install-Package System.Reactive.Linq
```

Comment: Argh! System.Reactive != System.Reactive.Core <facepalm>